# "It is not true that all the students drink coffee."

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$S(x)$ means $x$ is a student.

$C(x)$ means $x$ drinks coffee.

I need to turn the statement

> "It is not true that all the students drink coffee."

into predicate logic. This is what I have.

¬(∀x, ¬C(x) ∨S(x))

I think it is somewhat correct but I am not sure. I think I am wrong because the next part asks me to simplify the logical expression using the logical equivalence of
$p \implies q \equiv \neg p \vee q$.

What is that asking me to do? Do I have to use my current answer and convert it or is this a completely new thing?

Comment: Your answer to the first statement is correct.  You could verify the second statement by using a truth table.

Comment: The problem is you have already translated "it's not true that for every x, P(x)" into "there is a x such that not P(x)". It's correct, but it's not what you were asked to do. The statement should rather be written $\lnot(\forall x, S(x)\implies C(x))$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Ok, that makes more sense. This would result in using the logic equivalance to get ¬(∀x, ¬C(x) ∨S(x)) which means "it is not true that for every student, there is a student or a non coffee drinker."? is there a more efficient way of saying this?

Comment: You have it wrong, $A\implies B$ is equivalent to $B\vee \lnot A$. Apart from that, it's ok. Later on you will simplify: $\lnot (\forall x, P(x))$ is equivalent to $\exists x, \lnot P(x)$.

Comment: For me it looks that it should be ¬(∀x, ¬S(x) ∨ C(x) ), because the only way of the proposition ¬S(x) ∨ C(x) to be false is both being false, which coincides with the proposition S(x) $\rightarrow$ C(x). In resume, saying that all students drinks coffe means ∀x,  S(x) $\rightarrow$ C(x), and not it being true means ¬( ∀x,  S(x) $\rightarrow$ C(x)), which is equivalent to  ¬(∀x, ¬S(x) ∨ C(x) ).

Comment: Are you not saying that the only people that drinking coffee are students?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from the comments, we have $S(x) = $ "$x$ is a student", and $C(x) = $ "$x$ drinks coffee."

So for every student to drink coffee means: $\forall x(S(x) \to C(x))$. We have the statement that not all students drink coffee, so we will negate our statement. First lets convert $\to$ to its logical equivalent: $p \to q \equiv \lnot p \lor q$.

Now let's throw the negation in front of our statement and converting $\to$ to its logical equivalent, we have:
$$\lnot \forall x(\lnot S(x) \lor (C(x))
\\
\exists x \lnot (\lnot S(x) \lor C(x)) \qquad \lnot \forall x \equiv \exists x
\\
\text{Now we will follow the negation through.}
\\
\exists x(\lnot \lnot S(x) \land \lnot C(x)) \qquad \lnot \lor \equiv \land 
\\
\boxed{\exists x(S(x) \land \lnot C(x))} \qquad \lnot \lnot p\equiv p \space \text{Double negation.}
$$

Now this translates to, "There exists a student and they do not drink coffee."